# jQuery bind and getJSON combo not behaving as expected

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am loading a jQuery UI dialog and at the end of the HTML that I get with an AJAX call is the script below. I expect it to bind to a button that I have defined and to run when clicked, however it does not run. If I change the contents of the function to nothing but an alert it runs fine. JSLint has not helped me to find my problem. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#runbutton").bind("click",function()
    {
        $("#loading").show();
        $.getJSON("web.air.sum.rpt.php","json=true&whse="+$("#whse").val()+"&date1="+$("#date1").val()+"&date2="+$("#date2").val()+"&status="+$("#status").val()+"&caby="+$("#caby").val()+"&catarg="+$("#catarg").val(),function(data, textStatus)
            {
                $("#results").html("<table width='100%' id='restbl'></table>");
                $("#loading").hide();
                $.each(data,function(key,val)
                {
                    $("#restbl")
                        .append("<tr><th>AIR "+val.KEY+"</th><td>"+val.ACCDATE+" "+val.ACCTIME+"</td></tr>")
                        .append("<tr><th>Team Member</th><td>"+val.NAME+"</td></tr>");
                        .append("<tr><th>Target</th><td>"+val.TARDATE+"</td></tr>");
                        .append("<tr><th>Accident Description</th></tr><tr><td colspan='2'>"+val.ACCDESC+"</td></tr>");
                        .append("<tr><th>Corrective Action</th></tr><tr><td colspan='2'>"+val.CORRACT+"</td></tr>");
                        .append("<tr><td></td><td>By "+val.VERBY+"</td></tr>");
                        .append("<tr><td colspan='2'><hr></td></tr>");
                });
            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's there. I fixed the alignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have semicolons after your .append() functions.  This should only be so after the last one.

Comment: That was it. Thanks for catching that one.